# defaultPrefs not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have created a Prefs Controller class, which dose what it says controlls my prefs values. I have two specific values in my prefs both strings one that's called installSelected and the other called finishSelected, I setting them as a string that's either T or F...

When the app first starts I create the new prefs and the values are set to F automatically as those are their default values in the plist bundle. Then later in the app I overwrite installSelected to T. When I restart the application it returns the correct value as T. Then I write over it again using F. Again I restart but when I read the values this time it still shows T when it should be F.

I have debugged this and I am just not sure why it's not saving the value.

This is what my prefController method looks like that is used to write the new values:

```
- (void) writeBool:(NSString *)name MyBool:(NSString *)myboolString {

    prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    if ([name isEqualToString:@"InstallsSelected"]) {
        [prefs setObject:myboolString forKey:name];
    }
    else if ([name isEqualToString:@"FinishSelected"]) {
        [prefs setObject:myboolString forKey:name];
    }

    [prefs synchronize];
}
```

I call the above method like this

```
[prefsController writeBool:@"InstallsSelected" MyBool:@"F"];
```

It just makes no sense that it's not working as I am able to change it from F to T but not back if needed and none of the code is different. What might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using strings instead of bool values?

You have to set your boolean by using:

```
// Notice setBool
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"pref"];
```

and call synchronize after it:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve the value, you call:

```
// Notice boolForKey
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"pref"]) {
   // False
} else {
   // True
}
```

To register default prefs, use:

```
NSDictionary *appDefaults = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"pref1",
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"pref2",
                                 nil];

NSUserDefaults * prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

Comment: There was a weird issue I ran into where when starting the application it wouldnt instantiate with the default value. so I was having to programically set it after starting which I didnt like. So I decided to just do it with a string which was working well for me up untill this point.

Comment: okay thanks I will give this a try now.. might take me abit but I'll make sure to come back with any questions or answers.

Comment: Have you succeeded? :)

Comment: No I am still working on it. I dont want to change to a Bool, The logic is fine its just this stupid prefrence Controller class I have made is not working how it should. It updates to True fine but it will never update back to False.....

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the simulator or a real device? I have had serious problems getting the sync right in the Simulator. It turns out that if you just do a rebuild from xCode, the user preferences are not saved. They are saved if you bring the app to the background in the Simulator (press cmd-shift-H).

Also it helps to NSLog as much as possible to see what is written in the prefs.

Comment: God sorry, I edited the keyword to represent something meaningfull as currently its abit jibberish but I can assure you the case is correct in my code... sorry about that I have updated my question.

Comment: I am doing this on the device... HOWEVER my rebuild consists of me pressing the run button in xcode.. I think I will try disconnecting it and running though the motions of it.. I will let you know how i go. I have tracked step by step procedures so it will be easy to tell if it works or not by following those.

Comment: Yea it is still not working correctly. The logic is really simple so its not that its just that for some reason the values are not saving correctly when writing from F to T